# Assigning "bare" numbers to newtypes

Tags: haskell, pragma

Note the second line in this GHCi session. What is it about the Latitude type that allows me to use a "bare" number as a value, instead of having to invoke a constructor? I would like to do something similar with some of my own types.

```
λ> :m + Data.Geo.GPX.Type.Latitude                                                                                                   
λ> let t = 45 :: Latitude                                                                                                            
λ> t                                                                                                                                 
45.0
```

I've examined the source code for the Latitude type, but I had trouble figuring it out at first. Eventually I found the answer, so I thought I'd document it here. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Haskell98 standard, numeric literals are actually calls to `fromInteger` and `fromRational`. This allows them to be converted to any type that implements those functions ([fromInteger](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afromInteger) is in the Prelude.Num typeclass and [fromRational](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afromRational) is in the Prelude.Fractional typeclass).

> The syntax of numeric literals is given in Section 2.5. An integer
>   literal represents the application of the function fromInteger to the
>   appropriate value of type Integer. Similarly, a floating literal
>   stands for an application of fromRational to a value of type Rational
>   (that is, Ratio Integer). Given the typings:
>
> fromInteger  :: (Num a) => Integer -> a
>
> fromRational :: (Fractional a) => Rational -> a
>
> integer and floating literals have the typings (Num a) => a and
>   (Fractional a) => a, respectively. Numeric literals are defined in
>   this indirect way so that they may be interpreted as values of any
>   appropriate numeric type. See Section 4.3.4 for a discussion of
>   overloading ambiguity.

http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html#numeric-literals

Answer (score 6):

What makes this work is that the type is a Num. The easiest way to do that is to use "deriving Num", in which case I need the language pragma GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving. So I can create a type like the following,

```
newtype Seconds = Seconds Double deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Num, Fractional, Floating, Real, RealFrac, RealFloat, Show)
```

And then in GHCi,

```
λ> let s = 5 :: Seconds                                                                                                              
λ> s                                                                                                                                 
Seconds 5.0
```

Alternatively, I could explicitly implement Num.

Comment: To be exact, it's the fact that `Seconds` is in the `Num` class that makes it work.  It doesn't matter how it became a member of the `Num` class.

Comment: It would also work if the instance were explicitly provided rather than derived. All you need is an `instance Num`.

Comment: so does the literal number desugar to `fromInteger n`? Is there similar functionality for other numeric class instances, e.g. a literal floating point number?

Comment: @jberryman see missingno's answer. Floating point literals have an implicit `fromRational`, similar to how integral literals have an implicit `fromInteger`. Those are the only two cases of automagical number transformation that I know of.